# I'm trying to create a slick slider, but my slick slider isn't working. No error shows in the console as well

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So i've been trying to use slick slider for my website. I have all the files in the correct folder, there is no error in my console. My images are cards are showing but these are in line vertically, and i don't know what I'm doing wrong. here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Palvisha Shoaib</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href = "style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href = "slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href = "slicktheme.css">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div class="box6">
    <section class="variable slider">
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m7">
            <div class="card" style="width: 250px;">
<div class="card-content">
                <p>content</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m7">
        <div class="card" style="width: 250px;">
        <div class="card-content">
                <p>content</p>
              </div></div>
             </div>
        </div>
      </section>
     </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking on this website, it has an in-depth tutorial on the slick slider. https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I can see that you don't have this function in your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>
```